# Is there a way to see how many coins you have of your daily limit?

Tags: pokemon-go

If one of your pokemon is kicked out of a gym, you get up to 50 poke coins per day.

But sometimes you miss the notification that one of your pokemon has ben knocked out and so you lose the count of how many coins you have for the day.

Is there somewhere you can see the number of coins you are at for the day?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a recent update, you can now see how many coins you accrued each day. The amount of accrued coins for a given day will appear on the “today” tab of the research section.

[image: Today tab with earned coins]

Answer (score 8):

There is no place to see it immediately (would be a good addition to the game though).

But, as @Wondercricket mentioned, you can count the coins you've earned today from Pokeball icon -> News -> Notifications. The Notifications include also recent friend related activity, so you might have to scroll it a bit down. Formerly they were seen in Journal, but the most recent update changed the location.

Comment: I thought this was not working. But then realised that it's not the same as the journal.